# Canonical project layout for Java projects?

Tags: java

Is there an official documented (from Oracle) or de facto best practice for structuring a Java project, in terms of layout and required files?

---

Comparing to Swift modules for inclusion in iOS apps. Apple does not publish a guide for project layout. However CocoaPods is probably considered canonical in this space and [they do publish a template](https://github.com/CocoaPods/pod-template) for laying out your projects in this space.

Comment: What about the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)?

Comment: An Eclipse project will be structured differently from a NetBeans project; a Maven project different from a Gradle project, etc.  There is no "canonical, one-size-fits-all" project structure that applies across all the variations of potential Java projects.

Comment: Well, one could say that the directory structure of Maven projects is widely used.